# Combine createStackNavigator and createBottomTabNavigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

**Scenario :**

- I have an app working with three tabs for navigation (School, Admin, Family);
- I am now trying to add in other screens, that will not have corresponding tabs. These screens will be navigated to using something like this.props.navigation.navigate('ChatScreen')

**Issue** 
- With my past solution, any time I added a screen it would add a tab for that screen.

**Todo :**

- I would like to have the tabs in my navigation stack, as well as other normal (not-tab) screens.

  - I would like both the tabs and the header to be persistent
- I have been unsuccessful at combining both, and have tried many
  variations of the code below.

**Tried Code :**

```
const School = createStackNavigator({
  School: { 
  screen: SchoolScreen, 
  navigationOptions: {
  headerTitle: <CustomHeaderTitle screen='school'/>
    }
  }
 });

const Admin = createStackNavigator(
  { Admin: {
  screen: AdminScreen,
  navigationOptions: {
    headerTitle: <CustomHeaderTitle screen='admin' />
      }
    }
  });

 const Family = createStackNavigator(
  {
   Family: {
      screen: FamilyScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
      headerLeft: null,
      headerTitle: <CustomHeaderTitle screen='family' />
      }
     }
    }
);

const ChatStack = createStackNavigator({
  CreateChat: CreateChatScreen
});

const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    School: School,
    Admin: Admin,
    Family: Family
  },
  {
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({

  tabBarIcon: () => {
    const { routeName } = navigation.state;
    return <Image id={1} source={require('./app/img/school_logo.png')} />
  },
  tabBarLabel: navigation.state.routeName
}),
tabBarOptions: {
  activeTintColor: 'tomato',
  inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    height: 55
  }
}

  }
);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Root: ChatStack,
  Tabs: TabStack
})

export default class App extends Component {
  render() { return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootStack />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

I apologize, I cannot get this code to format after fighting with it for some time.

Thank you for any help or recommendations in advance!

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Credit to an unnamed redditor:

You'll have to nest you're entire stack into each screen of the tab navigator. As far as I know you can't access different screens in a StackNavigator if they are nested inside a different TabNavigator screen.

For example, if you want to be able to navigate to the chat screen from the SchoolScreen, you'll have to include that component inside your School navigator.

```
 const School = createStackNavigation({
   School: {
       screen: SchoolScreen
   },
   SchoolChat: {
       screen: CreateChatScreen
   } 
 });
```

From there your main TabNavigator should look about the same

```
const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
    School: School
});
```

Comment: When I goback the defined tabnavigatior (Footer) i will not appear.

Answer (score 2):

you should hide the RootStack header when TabStack is focused

```
TabStack.navigationOptions = {
  // Hide the header from root stack
  header: null,
};
```

and you did not need add stack to CreateChatScreen

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs: TabStack,
  ChatScreen: CreateChatScreen,
})
```

Comment: Hi, maybe there was a miscommunication in the original intention of my post. My goal is not to hide the tabs when I navigate to another screen. I would like the tabs to be persistent, as they currently are, but I would also like to be able to navigate to other 'non-tab' screens using something like this.props.navigation.navigate('ChatScreen'). Using your solution, I now just see a Create Chat Screen with no tabs. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Maybe I have a bit of a mistake, TabStack needs to be put in front and has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In react native navigation 5

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


function Scr(){
  return <Text>hello</Text>;
}
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Expolre"
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: '#414757',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Expolre" component={Scr} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function Routing() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="login"
          component={Scr}
          options={{header: () => null}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="dashboard"
          component={MyTabs}
          options={{header: () => null}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```